# Trying to understand why mDataByteSize property of AudioBuffer is changing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code which I'm using to read the contents of a WAV file into an `SInt16` array:

```
AudioBufferList *buffers;
UInt32 ablSize = offsetof(AudioBufferList, mBuffers) + 
    (sizeof(AudioBuffer) * 1);
buffers = malloc(ablSize);

buffers->mNumberBuffers = 1;
buffers->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
buffers->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = dataByteSize;

UInt32 dataSize = (UInt32)fileLengthFrames * sizeof(SInt16);

self.extractedSamples = malloc(dataSize);
self.extractedByteCount = dataByteSize; 

UInt32 totalFramesRead = 0;
do {
    UInt32 framesRead = (UInt32)fileLengthFrames - totalFramesRead;
    buffers->mBuffers[0].mData = self.extractedSamples + 
        (totalFramesRead * sizeof(SInt16));
    ExtAudioFileRead(eaf, &framesRead, buffers);
    totalFramesRead += framesRead;

} while (totalFramesRead < fileLengthFrames);

free(buffers);
```

This is working fine for files of < 0.5 seconds duration. But for a longer file I'm testing, the app crashes with a bad access error inside the `do` loop. For this file, `dataByteSize` is 60472, and at the start of the loop `buffer->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize` is also 60472. But when the crash occurs, I see that `buffer->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize` has changed to 57300, which is presumably why the crash is now occurring.

Anybody know how/why this value is changing in the middle of the loop? One guess I have is that I'm not properly retaining the `AudioBufferList` and the memory space for `mDataByteSize` is somehow getting overwritten.

**Edit:** When this code is run on the simulator with the same file, it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

mDataByteSize should be set to framesRead * sizeof(SInt16) * channelCount before each call to ExtAudioFileRead